# Надстройка для Outlook

Tags: c#

Не могу разобраться как написать надстройку для Outlook 2013 что бы приходящие письма от определённого адресата сохранялись на диске

Comment: Начните [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc668191.aspx).

Comment: там я был в первую очередь.Не чего что мне бы помогло не подошло

Comment: Значит вы можете написать, собрать и запустить надстройку для Outlook, верно? Значит вам надо уточнить вопрос. Что именно у вас не получается. Например, если вам не удается получить входящие письма от определенного отправителя, напишите что проблема именно с этим -  с получением списка писем. Напишите также что вы пытались сделать для получения этих писем и что именно не получилось. Тогда кто-то кто имеет такой опыт сможет вам помочь.

Comment: Может Вам просто нужен фильтр, а не надстройка?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду макрос?